# Calculate the value of a floating-point coordinate in a 2d-matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a 2D matrix that has 2 rows and 2 columns with these values:

```
x=0, y=0 => 1    
x=1, y=0 => 2    
x=0, y=1 => 3    
x=1, y=1 => 4
```

I can calculate the values for cells with integer coordinates, such as (0,0) and (1,0), etc. by a simple lookup.

However I need to do this for any floating-point coordinate.
From intuition I got to the following assumptions thus far:

```
(0.25, 0) I believe would be 0.75 x 1 + 0.25 x 2
(0, 0.25) I believe would be 0.75 x 1 + 0.25 x 3
(0.5, 0.5) I believe is the sum of all 4 cells divided by 4
```

However I could be completely wrong.. I couldn't think of the right terms to look this problem up.

My goal is to be able to calculate the value of any coordinate like (0.25, 0.25) but I think I may have forgotten some basic matrix rules from my maths classes, because the best I can come up sounds a bit complicated for what I'm trying to do.

My current idea is to calculate the distance from every cell "centre" (for which I know the value) and using the Pythagorean theorem calculate the distance of each cell, and then average the cell values based on their distance from the point.

Is there a simpler approach perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a two dimensional function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and the values $f(0,0)$, $f(0,1)$, $f(1,0)$ and $f(1,1)$ in your initial matrix.

If you want more values, here it seems $f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$, you must make some assumption about $f$.

A simple assumption is that $f$ is a linear function on $[0,1]^2$. 
Under this assumption you can use linear interpolation.
Interpolation along the axes gives:
$$
f(x,y) = (1-x) f(0,y) + x f(1,y) \\
f(x,y) = (1-y) f(x, 0) + y f(x, 1)
$$
we combine this into
$$
f(x,y) = (1-x)[(1-y)f(0,0) + y f(0,1)] + x [(1-y) f(1,0) + y f(1,1)]
$$
Note that if the four corner values do not lie on a common plane, this function will be some quadratic function through those four points.

[image: example]

You can fiddle with the example [here](https://ggbm.at/ThdfuMf9). (Move the four sliders with the corner values in the middle view)

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes you're right, the actual solution I was after was bilinear interpolation.

Comment: I added a GeoGebra example.